# getting negative length value of bytearray

Tags: java, android

```
soc = new Socket(ip, port1);
    while (true)
    {
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
        int len = dis.readInt();
        Log.d("===============" + len, "-------------------" + len);
        byte data[] = null;
        data = new byte[len];
        dis.readFully(data);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, len);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
```

This is my android code which takes the byte array from server and it display in Image.I am getting negative value of length of byte array and so app gets stopped. The above code working properly in PC. and also tell me whether I am doing right method for displaying image to screen in android.

Logcat field:

```
03-03 12:50:27.941: E/AndroidRuntime(7283): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-205
03-03 12:50:27.941: E/AndroidRuntime(7283): java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -1393754107
03-03 12:50:27.941: E/AndroidRuntime(7283):     at com.example.vnc.Screen$1.run(Screen.java:47)
03-03 12:50:27.941: E/AndroidRuntime(7283):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Server Side:

```
        while(continueLoop){

        try{
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);


        byte[] imageInByte;

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image,"jpg", baos);
        baos.flush();
        imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        baos.close();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeInt(imageInByte.length);
        System.out.println(imageInByte.length);
        dos.write(imageInByte);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        dos.flush();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
                   try{
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> This is my android code which takes the byte array from server and it display in Image.I am getting negative value of length of byte array and so app gets stopped.

What your code is doing is reading an `int` which it is interpreting an array size.  And sometimes the value it reading is negative ... which is nonsense.

I suspect that the real problem is that the way that you are reading the data does not match the way that you wrote it.  If you showed us the code that does the writing (or its specification) we would have a better chance of telling you what the actual problem is, and recommending a solution that will *actually* work.

---

**UPDATE**

I think I get it.  I think that this is due to some internal buffering in the `DataOutputStream` ... combined with the fact that you are opening a new `DataOutputStream` each time you go round the loop.  What happens is this:

1. One time around the loop, you open the `DataInputStream` and read from it.  This cause all currently available bytes to be buffered.
2. Then you read the size and the bytes, leaving the first few bytes of the next "message" unread in the buffer.
3. But next time round the loop you open another `DataInputStream`.  This discards the unread bytes, and causes the reader to read a "length" from the wrong place in the logical stream; i.e. some random point in an image.  The chances are > 50% that this will *look* like a negative or large positive value ... leading to the exception.

Move this line to before the loop:

```
 DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
```

You should probably do the same thing on the server side too, though the fact that you are explicitly flushing `dos` should save you there.

Comment: Do the length values printed on the client and server side match?

Comment: No. As server sends proper data but client get -ve or very big size its connection get closed and so server also get closed. but size are different

Comment: Do you understand the explanation?  Did you move the declaration to *before* the loop ... so that only one `DataInputStream` gets created?

Comment: yes.i have put the DataInputStream line out od the loop for using same object every time. correct me if i am wrong. Should i also move dataOutPutStream line out of the loop

Comment: Yea ... but I don't think it matters.

Comment: Then you should try to debug this.  On the client side, set a breakpoint on the first statement in the loop, and look at the DataInputStream data structures to find out what bytes are buffered.  There has to be some rational explanation for why the length is wrong when you read it.

Comment: what to do? i have also put dataoutputstream out side the loop

Comment: Debug it.  Set a breakpoint at the appropriate point in your code and watch exactly what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

use Guava's UnsignedBytes utilities to view Java bytes as unsigned
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedBytes.html